# Getting repeated API calls from Android App to a Rails App

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, webserver

I have an application which has two systems. One is an Android App and the other is a RAILS App. RAILS App has exposed certain APIs which the Android App Calls.

Many a times it is noticed, that an API call is repeatedly sent to the RAILS App. As in, the Android App calls a POST URL and then the same call can be seen two times hitting the RAILS App. The response of the second call is sent back to the Android App.

Does this issue seem to be on the application(Android/RAILS) end or the Web Server / Network end.

NOTE: I have noticed that this happens only on slow network like 2G. When on 3G or WiFi the API calls get executed only once.